# ObjectInput/OutputStream from Java to Android

Tags: java, android, data-structures, data-stream

I'm developing a Java SE application that does save its content as a Serializable object through a ObjectOutputStream.

My question is, reading a ObjectInputStream in a Android native app will correctly load the content?

And plus: there's another simple way to save data structures (that supports modification of the model classes)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes.
2. There are many, such as XML beans, JSON, etc, but you should also be aware that Serialization supports extensive versioning facilities as well ('modification of classes'). There's a whole chapter about it in the Object Serialization Specification.

Comment: Good, I think the default serialization is enough for me, but theres versioning at docs? can you post a link?